# Jaxx Wallet ---> Cryptopea Wallet - unsuccessfull (doublespend)

Tags: transactions

I attempted to transfer funds from my *bitcoin jaxx wallet* to my *cryptopia exchange bitcoin wallet*.

However transaction looks like it failed with doublespend error report.

[image: jaxxwallet to cryptopia wallet]

Anything I can do?

This is the error.
[image: error report]

and further down info.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to contact your wallet support team, let them know that you had this issue so that they can dig deeper maybe..

But as i can see transaction was confirmed so your coins was delivered to you, so you are fine.

See what is double spending, buy looks like your coins didn't succeed to double spend, so you are fine.

---

**What is Double-spending?**

Double-spending is the result of successfully spending some money more than once. Bitcoin protects against double spending by verifying each transaction added to the block chain to ensure that the inputs for the transaction had not previously already been spent.

More information: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Double-spending